# ASP.Net - Sorting a GridView without postback (bound to a generic list)

Tags: asp.net, gridview, webforms

I'm trying to sort the columns for a GridView in ASP.Net, ideally without refreshing the page.

My data is compiled into a generic list on the server and bound to the GridView in the code-behind.

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
BackColor="White" CellPadding="3" GridLines="Vertical" AllowSorting="True" 
CssClass="GridViewStyle" EnableSortingAndPagingCallbacks="True" 
AllowPaging="True">
    <Columns>
      <asp:BoundField DataField="ID" HeaderText="ID" SortExpression="ID">
      </asp:BoundField>
      <asp:BoundField DataField="Title" HeaderText="Title" SortExpression="Title">
      </asp:BoundField>                            
      <asp:BoundField DataField="Customer" HeaderText="Customer" SortExpression="Customer">
      </asp:BoundField>                            
    </Columns>
```

When I try to click any of the column headers, nothing happens.

Is there any way to accomplish this without refreshing the page?

Comment: No with asp.net Gridview component, because is a server component. It doesn't have almost any client behavior. You will need to use some other type of component, either a javascript component or something hybrid.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there is no way to accomplish this with a Gridview alone without causing a postback.

You can sort it on the client side with JavaScript (perhaps by abandoning GridView and instead using a Repeater combined with [jQuery DataTables](https://datatables.net/))

Or you can use an UpdatePanel or iframe to mask the postback. Those have their own complications and are probably not the best approach however. I personally absolutely hate using either of them and recommend you steer clear.